# Is an msi product code the same for on all machines

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-installer, uninstallation

Sorry if this seems like a silly question but I couldn't find any information.

Say I install software with the same msi installer (in this case I'm installing Postgresql) would the product number be the same across all windows machine?

I'm asking this because I need to create an installation script that calls

```
MsiExec.exe /I{Product Number HERE}
```

So I can launch the GUI uninstaller. I don't want to do something like:

```
CMD /C WMIC product where name="PostgreSQL 8.3" call uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same on all machines that have the same MSI installed.  Somehow when I get to a universe of 300,000 machines that isn't reliable anymore.  You eventually get to the point that you need to write robust scripts that can perform the queries and execute the uninstall commands that you don't want to do.